# append data into one array instead of having multi-nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an object and i want to append the object data into one array.

As of now i get something like this

[image]

This is a multi nested array, which doesn't make it easy to get a length count on the array, or map over the data. I want all the data to be within one array.

**Data Structure**

```
[
  [
    {
      "startTime": 1562273706436,
      "endTime": 1562273706530,
      "url": "http://localhost:3005/logtofile",
      "method": "get",
      "status": 200,
      "duration": "0:0094"
    }
  ],
  [
    [
      {
        "startTime": 1562273706436,
        "endTime": 1562273706530,
        "url": "http://localhost:3005/logtofile",
        "method": "get",
        "status": 200,
        "duration": "0:0094"
      }
    ],
    {
      "value": "blah blah",
      "name": "John"
    }
  ],
  [
    [
      {
        "startTime": 1562273706436,
        "endTime": 1562273706530,
        "url": "http://localhost:3005/logtofile",
        "method": "get",
        "status": 200,
        "duration": "0:0094"
      }
    ],
    [
      [
        {
          "startTime": 1562273706436,
          "endTime": 1562273706530,
          "url": "http://localhost:3005/logtofile",
          "method": "get",
          "status": 200,
          "duration": "0:0094"
        }
      ],
      {
        "value": "blah blah",
        "name": "John"
      }
    ],
    {
      "value": "blah blah",
      "name": "John"
    }
  ]
]
```

I'm using react, sorry if the code looks a little bit confusing, im trying to pass the values [0] in an array, etc.

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
   logData: [],
   url: 'http://localhost:3005/logtofile', // only logs if the url end point is consistent with the service end point
   show:false
  };
 componentWillMount() {
    const retrieveLogs = {
      method: "GET",
      url: this.state.url, 
    }
    consume.fetch(retrieveLogs)
      .then( async (res) => {
        const logData = [
          {
            startTime: res.logger[0].startTime,
            endTime: res.logger[0].endTime,
            url: res.logger[0].url,
            method: res.logger[0].method,
            status: res.logger[0].status,
            duration: res.logger[0].duration,   
          }
        ]
        console.log(logData);
        await this.setState({
            logData: [...this.state.logData, logData]
         })
        console.log(this.state.logData)
    })
  }
  onAddData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = {
      value:"blah blah",
      name:"John"
    }
    const postLogs = {
      method:"POST",
      url: this.state.url,
      data: [...this.state.logData, value]
    }
    consume.fetch(postLogs).then( (res) => {
      this.setState({
        logData: [...this.state.logData, res.data.data]
      })
    })
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(this.state.logData.length !== 0 && prevProps.logData === null){
      this.setState({
        show:true
      })
    }
    console.log(this.state.logData); // gets multinested arrays. 
  }
 ........
export default App;
```

Comment: The format seems off, is the data nesting intentional?

Comment: not intentional more like im not sure on what im doing. Working on a solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use Array.prototype.flat() to flatten your array (Or use a library or your own function if you're worried about browser compatibility).
- Filter the result array for logs

```js
let data = [
  [
    {
      "startTime": 1562273706436,
      "endTime": 1562273706530,
      "url": "http://localhost:3005/logtofile",
      "method": "get",
      "status": 200,
      "duration": "0:0094"
    }
  ],
  [
    [
      {
        "startTime": 1562273706436,
        "endTime": 1562273706530,
        "url": "http://localhost:3005/logtofile",
        "method": "get",
        "status": 200,
        "duration": "0:0094"
      }
    ],
    {
      "value": "blah blah",
      "name": "John"
    }
  ],
  [
    [
      {
        "startTime": 1562273706436,
        "endTime": 1562273706530,
        "url": "http://localhost:3005/logtofile",
        "method": "get",
        "status": 200,
        "duration": "0:0094"
      }
    ],
    [
      [
        {
          "startTime": 1562273706436,
          "endTime": 1562273706530,
          "url": "http://localhost:3005/logtofile",
          "method": "get",
          "status": 200,
          "duration": "0:0094"
        }
      ],
      {
        "value": "blah blah",
        "name": "John"
      }
    ],
    {
      "value": "blah blah",
      "name": "John"
    }
  ]
]

function isLog(objParam){
  if(!objParam.hasOwnProperty("startTime"))
   return false;
  if(!objParam.hasOwnProperty("endTime"))
   return false;
  if(!objParam.hasOwnProperty("url"))
   return false;
  if(!objParam.hasOwnProperty("method"))
   return false;
  if(!objParam.hasOwnProperty("status"))
   return false;
  if(!objParam.hasOwnProperty("duration"))
   return false;
    
   return true;
}

data.flat(10)
console.log(data.flat(10))
```

Comment: thanks for answering, however this approach is somewhat quite complex.

Comment: If you are dealing with multiple level nested arrays of different depth, you'll need recursion or loops. I would try to remove the recursion if possible

Comment: im looking for something more es6 friendly, this is quite complex. i apperciate your effort though, and will check back for any updates. thx.

Comment: I will accept answer, however i structured my data differently to avoid over coding.

Answer (score 0):

Restructured the code, and now it works good.

```
onAddData = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const value = {
    value:"blah blah",
    name:"John"
  }
  const postLogs = {
    method:"POST",
    url: this.state.url,
    data: {value: "more value"}
  }
  consume.fetch(postLogs).then( (res) => {
    this.setState({
      // flat takes the array out of the array
      logData: [...this.state.logData.flat(), res.logger[0]] // appends each log to an array 
    })
  })
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if(this.state.logData.length !== 0 && prevProps.logData === null){
    this.setState({
      show:true
    })
  }
  console.log(this.state.logData);
}
```